# Restarting flink streaming application

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

How do I can restart flink streaming application gracefully so that it starts reading(in case of kafka)from where it has left before stop ?

I read checkpoints work only in case of application failure and not while restarting application.

```
KafkaSource<Event> source = KafkaSource.<Event>builder()
                    .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                    //.setTopics("events", "event1")
                    .setTopics("events")
                    .setGroupId("my-group")
                    .setStartingOffsets(???)
```

Let me know what should be the starting offsets set to If application has to start from the checkpoint saved.

Comment: Checkpoints are done automatically and periodically. Savepoint on the other hand is done manually usually before stopping the app. During the app launch you can specify which savepoint to load in.

Comment: [Related docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/savepoints/)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the offsets are being committed in each checkpoint/savepoint (which is done by default if checkpointing is enabled), the source should start from `OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets()`